# dse gremlin-console is not working

Tags: groovy, datastax-enterprise, gremlin

I have installed and started DSE 5.0 with DSE Graph enabled. I am trying to work with graph using the gremlin-console.
However, I am encountering following error when I try to run commands.

```
gremlin> system.graphs()
No such property: system for class: groovysh_evaluate
Display stack trace? [yN] y
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: system for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:70)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:190)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.super$3$execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:124)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.(Console.groovy:174)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:361)
```

Can you please suggest any workaround to this problem.

Thanks and Regards,
Abbas

Comment: Can you post `dsetool status`? Just want to make sure your system is started properly. `system` should return someting like `==>com.datastax.bdp.graph.api.system.GraphSystem@6d353203`

Comment: Is this the first command? I believe `system` is no longer available, once you've configured an alias. Resetting the alias should make `system` available again.

Comment: Yes, I could see the cluster has been started properly.

Comment: Are you launching the Gremlin Console with `bin/dse gremlin-console` or are you trying to use a standalone Gremlin Console downloaded from the Apache TinkerPop site?

Comment: I am using 'dse gremlin-console'

Answer (score 4):

As I find out, where is a bug in DSE 5.0 init scripts for gremlin-console, so no correct initialization is performed on startup. Execute following and try again:

```
:remote close
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session-managed
:remote config timeout max
:remote console
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Tinkerpop 3.1.3 `max` became `none`:

```
:remote config timeout none
```